# Spring Boot CRON expression is not working properly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a Spring Boot application which will create a JAR file. In this application I have tow jobs to execute. One job is master job which saves data in MySQL database and second job perform some calculations and prepare some reports.

I need to execute master job at every 15 minutes and second job every 20 minute. So I used Spring Corn expression "* */15 * * * *" for master job and "* */20 * * * *" for second job. But the behavior of job execution is very abrupt. What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

**New Answer**
You are correct , i personally tested its working fine

test the cron executions using below code in java

```
CronTrigger t = new CronTrigger("* */15 * * * * ");
TriggerContext tc = new SimpleTriggerContext();
System.out.println("Current Time:" + new Date()+ " |Next Execution " + t.nextExecutionTime(tc));
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(new Date()); // Now use today date.
c.add(Calendar.MINUTE,16);
tc = new SimpleTriggerContext(c.getTime(),c.getTime(),c.getTime());
System.out.println("Current Time:" +c.getTime() + "Next Execution " + t.nextExecutionTime(tc));
c.add(Calendar.MINUTE,18);
tc = new SimpleTriggerContext(c.getTime(),c.getTime(),c.getTime());
System.out.println("Current Time:" + c.getTime() + "Next Execution " + t.nextExecutionTime(tc));
```

here are the imports

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.TriggerContext;
import org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger;
import org.springframework.scheduling.support.SimpleTriggerContext;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
```

---

**Old Answer**

You wrongly scheduled 1st Job Every  day at 3PM 
the correct cron is **`*/15 * * * *`** 
using

```
@Scheduled(cron = "*/15 * * * *")
```

You wrongly scheduled  second job at every day at 8PM 
the correct cron is **`*/20 * * * *`**

refer cron tab [`http://corntab.com/?c=*/20_*_*_*_*_`](http://corntab.com/?c=*/20_*_*_*_*_)

Comment: I used this * */15 * * * not this one */15 * * * *

Comment: Yes, you scheduled every day 3pm using  * */15 * * * ,
change it to every 15 mins using */15 * * * *

Comment: Spring cron is different than the regular one. Kindly read here https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html

Comment: the expression is correct that code shows the next execution time., I'm just moving the time further and seeing when it will execute further

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following expression and make sure you have handled exception properly.
0 */15 * * * * - Use this expression to run job every 15 min
0 */20 * * * * -Use this expression to run job every 20 min

Comment: can you explain the differences?

Comment: * Means to execute job at every time unit. First place denoting seconds it will try to run every seconds in every 15 minutes.
0 value used to run first second in every 15 minutes.

Kindly refer the below for more info
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html

Comment: Hi @FrancisRaj ,
The above answer satisfy your question?

Comment: Yeah Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Use following CRON for master job

```
0 0/15 * 1/1 * ?
```

Use following CRON for second job

```
0 0/20 * 1/1 * ?
```

Refer [Cron Maker](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

Comment: These crons for Linux machine or quartz. Spring crons are different. But I will try.

Comment: try like 
@Scheduled(cron = "*/15 * * * *")

it will work see my  answer
`http://corntab.com/?c=*/20_*_*_*_*_`

Answer (score 0):

Already couple of correct answers here, but if your requirement is to execute second job exactly after 15 mins once the first finishes you can use `fixedDelay`.

Sometimes it is necessary to ensure first run is completed, in such cases `fixedDelay` is the perfect solution.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 900000)
public void fixedDelayTask () {
  // Code
}
```

And don't forget to put `@EnableScheduling` on your `@Configuration` class.